# Remove 00:00:00 from the asp Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, datepicker

I have a textbox where I date using the `DatePicker` and save it. When I again come and check the date in the textbox the values are in

`02-04-1996 00:00:00`

I want to remove

> 00:00:00

Have a look at the image
[image: 00:00:00 in the Image]

How to do that ? Please help

**UPDATED CODE**

JS code for the Datepicker:-

```
$(function () {
        $("[id$=mainContent_txtdateofbirth], [id$=mainContent_txtdoj], [id$=mainContent_txtdol]").datepicker({
            textboxImageOnly: true,
            textboxImage: 'images/calendar.png',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: "{0:DD-MM-YY}",
            yearRange: "-40:+0",
            maxDate: new Date(),
        });
    });
```

Comment: How are you setting text in your textbox?

Comment: @Satpal: The Date is coming from the `DatePicker` which sets the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried like below and it worked:-

`codebehind`

```
txtdateofbirth.Text = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["dob"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();
```

`ToShortDateString();` removed the `00:00:00` from the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

> change the date-picker control property to custom.

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```

see [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx) `DateTimePicker.CustomFormat` Property

EDIT2:

> if you are using jQuery date picker.change the datepicker date format property.

try

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

[here 1](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) and [here 2](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) have some reference, you can see.

Comment: I have used the Jquery DatePicker, how to alter the code. See my updated question of the Javascript for datepicer..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the date sequence as follow:

**"0:DD-MM-YY"**

This will work!

Comment: where to put the sequence ?

Comment: right there in the alias where you specify the date format!

Comment: can you show that in the answer ?? Also i want this for textbox

Comment: The following code is for text box:                                                  `<asp:TextBox ID="txtServiceDate" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("ServiceDate","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>' ></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: Add `textmode="DateTime"`